# SAS key permissions getting change when using blobserviceclient

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage, azure-webapps

I am trying to upload files to blob storage in azure from a react webapp but am having issues with the signature in the authorization header.

This is how the sasToken looks in my code

```
const sasToken = `sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2021-09-22T00:41:33Z&st=2021-09-20T16:41:33Z&spr=https&sig=svP%2FecNOoteE%2**************%3D`;
const containerName = `containername`;
const storageAccountName = "acountname";
```

This is what it looks like the the GET and PUT requests of getBlobsInContainer and createBlobinContainer run.
`sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=ghostery&se=2021-09-22T00:41:33Z&st=2021-09-20T16:41:33Z&spr=https&sig=svP/FecNOoteE/**************=`
It's somehow overwriting the permission parameter in the token.

https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername?SAS&comp=list&restype=container&_=1632199288178
[image: This is the result of the GET request my code tries to run]
[image: This is the GET request when I change the url my codes trying to access to the rwdlacupx permissions]

The 3 functions I have to deal with it.

```
// return list of blobs in container to display
const getBlobsInContainer = async (containerClient) => {
  const returnedBlobUrls = [];
  // get list of blobs in container
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
    // if image is public, just construct URL
    returnedBlobUrls.push(
      `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blob.name}`
    );
  }

  return returnedBlobUrls;
};


const createBlobInContainer = async (containerClient, file) => {
  console.log(`initialising blobclient for ${file.name}`);
  // create blobClient for container
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(file.name);
  console.log("blobclient generated");
  // set mimetype as determined from browser with file upload control
  const options = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: file.type } };

  // upload file
  await blobClient.uploadBrowserData(file, options);
  console.log("Adding Metadata");
  await blobClient.setMetadata({UserName : 'Reynolds'});
};

const uploadFileToBlob = async (file) => {
  if (!file) return [];
  // get BlobService = notice `?` is pulled out of sasToken - if created in Azure portal
  const blobService = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`
  );
  console.log(`blobservice: https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/?${sasToken}`);

  // get Container - full public read access
  const containerClient = blobService.getContainerClient(containerName);

  // upload file
  await createBlobInContainer(containerClient, file);

  // // get list of blobs in container
  return getBlobsInContainer(containerClient);
};
```

I'm basically trying to figure out why this is happening and how to prevent/avoid it. The code runs till the `` console.log(`blobservice: https://${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/?${sasToken}`); `` before breaking due to Error 403 from invalid signature.

Comment: It may be because of the some url formatting

Comment: @SaGaR yeah I'm assuming its a problem with how the blobserviceclient appends the SAS key to the containerClient or something but I don't know how to address the issue

Comment: Turns out it actually firefox doing something whack to it. I'd like it to be able to work on that browser but doesn't seem to want to. Works fine on chrome and edge.

Comment: Thats good to hear.